# MySQL orders results randomly despite ORDER BY clause

Tags: mysql, sql

We're using the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT billing_invoice.id as 'billing_invoice.id' 
from billing_invoice 
inner join client_billing_invoice on client_billing_invoice.client_id = '1337' 
where billing_invoice.company_id = '7c701774-5046-4b9a-9a82-b0e9cac59794' or client_billing_invoice.client_id = '1337' 
group by billing_invoice.id 
order by billing_invoice.timestamp_created DESC limit 0,5
```

However it's randomly ordering the results despite the order and group by clauses. Is there's anything that I am missing here?

Answer (score 1):

This logic:

```
select billing_invoice.id
from . . .
group by billing_invoice.id
order by billing_invoice.timestamp_created desc
```

should return an error.  Why?  The `order by` is executed *after* the aggregation and there is no `billing_invoice.timestamp_created` after the `GROUP BY`.

This code should be generating a syntax error.  And it would in the more recent versions of MySQL (with the default settings).

You need an aggregation function:

```
order by max(billing_invoice.timestamp_created) desc
```